# A question on roots of unity in a field extension of odd degree.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Denote by $\mu_n(K)=\{ a \in K^\times : a^n=1\}$ and $\mu_\infty = \bigcup_n \mu_n(K)$.

> I want to show that if $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is an extension of an odd degree, then $\mu_\infty(K) = \mu_2(K)$.

Cheers!

Comment: Please show your work.

Comment: If $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is is an odd exentsion then it has an odd number of basis vectors, am I correct above $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: ah ok thanks I can see it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $a\in \mu_{n}(K)$ with $n$ odd.
Then, $\mathbb{Q}(a):\mathbb{Q}$ is an extension of degree $\phi(n)$.
$\phi(n)$ is always even, so $\mathbb{Q}(a)$ can't be a subfield of $K$.